# Projective bundle formula

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Given a projective bundle $\mathbb{P}(E)\to X$, is there any reference for the projective bundle formula for Hodge cohomology ring $\oplus H^p(X,\Omega_{X/k}^q)$?

Comment: (you means $X={\bf P}(E)$ in your formula) If $X$ is smooth and proper, then by Hodge decomposition the formula is the same as for singular cohomology (see Griffiths-Harris, p. 606). If $X$ is smooth but not necessarily proper then the cohomology ring might be infinite-dimensional.